# How do I Authenticate Into a Website that uses a csrf token using Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net, axios

The website that I want to authenticate into this website [https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHomeAccess](https://homeaccess.katyisd.org) and it uses a "__RequestVerificationToken" that always changes when you enter the website and the token is hidden in the html. I checked the payload when I logged in and it sent: [Payload When I logged into the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvNvw.png)

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

axios.get('https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn')
  .then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    const token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    const payload = {
      __RequestVerificationToken: token,
      SCKTY00328510CustomEnabled: 'True',
      SCKTY00436568CustomEnabled: 'True',
      Database: '10',
      VerificationOption: 'UsernamePassword',
      'LogOnDetails.UserName': 'TestName',
      tempUN: '',
      tempPW: '',
      'LogOnDetails.Password': 'TestPass'
    };

    return axios.post('https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn', payload);
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

When I tried this, all I got were errors and I am not sure why.

Comment: Can you show the error that you received? Is it possible to be some CORS errors?

Comment: It's a very long list, but if i shorten it, it basically just says that "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500" and this was the data that was sent: " data: '{"__RequestVerificationToken":"60eEeo_9yzcnriHFedCCM3XFyPBQrMfXZ2zbStfkIT24G5MbgbXhBd9ltmY_9Fo3t9C1_XqFaGedyjIENikWMdUifrTamhgRp9RzOJzkohA1","SCKTY00328510CustomEnabled":"True","SCKTY00436568CustomEnabled":"True","Database":"10","VerificationOption":"UsernamePassword","LogOnDetails.UserName":"TestName","tempUN":"","tempPW":"","LogOnDetails.Password":"TestPass"}'
  },"

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, the content type for your `/LogOn` API seems to be Form Data instead of JSON. In `axios.post()`, [the default content type is JSON](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example).

In order to post using Form Data, try to construct a `FormData` object instead (Documentation: https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart):

```js
const FormData = require('form-data');

axios.get('https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn')
  .then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    const token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('__RequestVerificationToken', token);
    form.append('SCKTY00328510CustomEnabled', 'True');
    form.append('SCKTY00436568CustomEnabled', 'True');
    form.append('Database', '10');
    form.append('VerificationOption', 'UsernamePassword');
    form.append('LogOnDetails.UserName', 'TestName');
    form.append('tempUN', '');
    form.append('tempPW', '');
    form.append('LogOnDetails.Password', 'TestPass');

    return axios.post('https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn', form);
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work, when I tried the code and substituted my own credentials it still said "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500"